# Unity - particle system material like this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, particles

Im trying to copy this fire system https://realtimevfx.com/t/sketch-10-jordanov/4273/7 the smoke here especially:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=Wwj3Y6ieTlI

So far not much luck, mainly because when I try to emulate the smoke by setting the material to a fade alpha, or even cutout alpha, the overlapping particles become this:

[image]

See, they overlap instead of being a solid stream. Is this not possible in Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few possibilities for this.

1. The texture you're using for your particle has the color fading to black on the RGB channels, instead of being pure white or blue and only having the alpha channel contain the circle pattern.
2. The shader being used is "pre-multiplying" the color by the alpha, giving a darker look around semitransparent overlaps.
3. The particles are being lit and thus differences in position can result in differences in lighting, breaking color/shading continuity.

If you use a Unity "Unlit" particle shader, there should be no visible overlaps, assuming you don't have the first issue. I'd recommend trying some of the other shader options available in the Particle section and Mobile>Particle section.